# Using PHP I want to create new text box based upon above select option

Tags: php

I am using following text box in my form

```
<?php
$Type = array  ("a" => "A" ,
        "b" => "B",
        "c" => "C",
        "d" => "D");    
?>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<div style="width: 25em;">
<lable for="Type">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Types :</lable>
<select name="Type" id="Type" size="1">
<option>Choose your required test </option>
<option value="a" name= "type_1"><?php echo $Type["a"] ?></option>
<option value="b" name= "type_2"><?php echo $Type["b"] ?></option>
<option value="c" name= "type_3"><?php echo $Type["c"] ?></option>
<option value="d" name= "type_4"><?php echo $Type["d"] ?></option>
</select></div>
```

Whenever user selects an option I wanted to display next steps,
for example if user selects A, then in next line automatically code should display information regarding A (such as price , place etc) in similar ways for B, c, D. 
I dont have any idea on java script and Jquery , please suggest me the query using php only.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp

Comment: A server side language cannot act upon client side actions. Either the user needs to click something, or you'll have to learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that without javascript, or posting the select and refresh the page.

Answer (score -1):

This is really a job for JQuery, and it would make your life *alot easier.* All you have to do to 'turn on' Jquery is put this in your  tags:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//javascript/jquery goes here
</script>
</head>
```

And to do what you're asking, would look like this:

```
$('#Type').change(function() {
   if ($(this).val() == 'a') {
      $('#div').html('Value A is chosen. HTML here can be outputted to an element.');
   }
   if ($(this).val() == 'b') {
      $('#div').html('Value B is chosen.');
   }
   //and so on
});
```